# How to set expiration of google code?

Tags: google-code

I host jquery from google code. When I check the site with page speed, I get this result:

> jquery-1.4.4.min.js (expiration not specified)

How can I set an expiration time for this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. I'd instead switch to fetching jquery via the Google Libraries API: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html.

That service is designed for low latency and high availability: it has all the appropriate cache headers set, is served from a CDN, etc. Google Code's subversion hosting will serve the file for you, but it was designed with slightly different objectives and won't work as well for this case.

Comment: Hi I'm using drupal and I have same problem with images, some expiry are not specified, what do I have to do in this case?
you can see for yourself here: http://backbone-design.com/ Many Thanks in advance